# Keeping a catalyst suspension suspended

Tags: catalysis, nanotechnology

I am currently working on a heterogeneous photocatalyst project.  We are having significant problems with the catalyst not staying suspended in an aqueous solution.  What can I do to prevent aggregation of an oxide catalyst.  I suspect there are lots of possible solutions.

Some extra details about my specific system:

- Aqueous solvent (pH: ~7)
- Nanoparticles around 100-200 nm
- Isoelectric point around pH 3 - 4
- Roughly 0.2 mg of catalyst / mL

Comment: Nobody can suggest anything to a generic query without knowing any details. Mention the particle size of the oxide.

Comment: I will add some details

Comment: It would depend on the reactivity of the oxides, and the tolerable viscosity. A first thought would be some organic dispersant, perhaps siloxanes. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0927775714001691

Comment: How about you do your literature study?

Comment: To float for how long? An initial thought was add either sodium dodecylsulfate (SDS) ([example](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257629091_Silver_nanoparticles_synthesis_in_aqueous_solutions_using_sulfite_as_reducing_agent_and_sodium_dodecyl_sulfate_as_stabilizer) and or polyethylene glycol (PEG). Vendors' lists may be an inspiration ([example](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/search?term=nanoparticle+dispersion&interface=All&N=0&mode=partialmax&lang=en&region=US&focus=product)), «NP ink»  and «quantum dot» (both used e.g., for printing organic electronics) equally may yield hits.